# Safari: how to allow user to download javascript object as text file with specific name

Tags: javascript, download, safari

I am trying to allow a user to download a large JSON object as a text file.  Currently, I am doing the following:

```
this.data.responseB64 = window.btoa(JSON.stringify(someObj));
```

The data object gets passed into a handlebars template and an href is there for download as follows:

```
<a class="btn btn-block" download="report.txt" href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,{{responseB64}}">
```

This works perfectly in FireFox and Chrome.  However, in earlier versions of Safari this doesn't work at all and in Safari 10 a file called "unknown" with no extension is downloaded (with the correct data).

Is there a better way to do this so that it is compatible with Safari as well?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: I'm aware that the download attribute isn't supported in Safari - asking for alternate solutions.

Comment: send a request to the server and have it return header to force a download.